# Error while integrating google OAuth with superset

Tags: django, authentication, google-oauth, ip, apache-superset

To integrate Google authentication into my Superset application, which is running on a specific IP address, I followed these steps:

1. Created an OAuth client ID on the Google Cloud Platform. To create it, a JavaScript Authorized Origin is required, which is basically the application's URL. Since my Superset application does not have a domain, I masked the <superset-IP> with a random domain ([http://localtesting.com](http://localtesting.com/)) in my local **`etc/hosts`** file. I used this masked domain in the Google Console for creating the client ID.
2. 1. Updated the **`superset_config.py`** file with the client ID, client secret, and app domain. Here is the file for your reference:

   ```
   from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_OAUTH

       ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
       AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_OAUTH
       OAUTH_PROVIDERS = [
           {
               "name": "google",
               "icon": "fa-google",
               "token_key": "access_token",
               "remote_app": {
                   "client_id": "<ClientId",
                   "client_secret": "<ClientSecretKey>",
                   "api_base_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/",
                   "client_kwargs": {"scope": "email profile"},
                   "request_token_url": None,
                   "access_token_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
                   "authorize_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                   "authorize_params": {"hd": "http://locatesting.com"}
               },
           }
       ]
       AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'
       AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Public'
   ```
3. Restarted the VM where superset is hosted.

After completing these steps, I encountered a 502 Bad Gateway error. My Superset application is using an Nginx server.

Is this issue somehow associated to nginx or anything wrong in masking of IP in my local machine

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Actually i had installed the dependency in the VM instead of superset virtual environment.